# ESRI SRID in QGIS Cloud invalid

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-cloud

I get many of my layers from my state of New Hampshire (US) repository, all come with the CRS `ESRI:103483 - NAD_1983_CORS96_StatePlane_New_Hampshire_FIPS_2800_Ft_US`. When attempting to transfer to QGIS Cloud every layer has SRID (here 103483) INVALID. That means I have to housekeep every new layer to a valid SRID. The question is why make some SRIDs invalid and why isn't there any documentation of this Cloud constraint?

QGIS 3.30, QGIS Cloud plugin 3.8.

Comment: Maybe QGIS Cloud understands only EPSG definitions but not ESRI ones.

Comment: It looks like EPSG didn't add the state plane zones based on CORS96. A close approximation would be the one based on NAD83 HARN, EPSG:3445.

Answer (score 2):

We have just published the latest version 3.8.1 of the QGIS Cloud Plugin. It fixes the incorrect handling of a few CRS and should solve your problem. Please give it a try.

Comment: As the developer of the bug fix can you give more details.  Will all authority codes be valid in the future, ESRI, OGC, EPSG... or is it a limited set?

Comment: All authority codes defined in the `spatial_ref_sys` table are valid in the future.

Comment: Sorry, no; 3.8.1 doesn't fix my SRID invalid issue.